# Not able to ping connected ubuntu server on local network?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I'm hoping some networking experts can help me track a weird problem.

I recently set up an ubuntu machine on my home network as a "home lab" of sorts. My plan is to use it as a server, where I can do various coding experiments.

Every couple of days or so, I seem to lose network access to this machine. I can't ssh to it or ping it. Since I set it up a week ago, I've been able to ping and ssh to it.

The obvious answer is that the server machine is no longer on the network. However, I can see on my router's website that my server IS actually connected and at the IP address I'm using for pings and ssh.

I have also physically logged on to the server and pinged sites on the internet and the results show that my machine is actually connected to the internet.

From the server, I ssh into itself by using its IP address and it connects fine! This means that open-ssh service is running as well.

Back to my laptop, I still can't ssh into the server or even ping it.

One potential reason is that I'm using T-mobile's 5G home internet device which automatically uses 2.4 ghz or 5 ghz. Could it be that one machine is on 2.4 ghz and the other is on 5 ghz? Isn't that how all wifi routers work these days?

Any ideas what could be causing this?

**Edit**:

I download an app on my iphone which allows me to ping machines so I have a third device to do the tests on my home network

Note, although ping and ssh to my server used to work, I don't think I ever tried pinging my windows laptop (icmp may be disabled by firewall or just turned off by default)

```
server to cnn.com ping: working
laptop to cnn.com ping: working

server to laptop ping: not working
laptop to server ping: not working

iphone to server ping: working!
iphone to laptop ping: not working

laptop to iphone ping: working!
server to iphone ping: working!
```

**Edit 2**:

`arp -a -v' on windows shows the server IP, but the 'Type' is shown is "invalid".